# Unable to Merge two account and giving the "Database.MergeResult = Invalid field IsCustomerPortal for merge;MERGE_FAILED;"

Tags: apex, account, database, merge

```
private static void DuplicateAccountMerge(List<Account> triggerNew)

{ 
       
try{

        // Merges a new Account with an existing Account based on matching email addresses.
        // Old Account is the Master Account- New Account information will be added to the Master Account only where the Master Account information is blank
       
        // Set up variables
        List<Id> triggerId = new List<Id>();
        List<String> triggerEmail = new List<String>();
       
        // Read trigger into variable(s)
        for (Account acc : Triggernew)
            {
                triggerId.add(acc.Id);
                triggerEmail.add(acc.PersonEmail);            
            }
     
        // Get all Account fields formatted for use in a SOQL query
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> AllLeadFields = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account').getDescribe().SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
     
         List<String> accessiblefields = new List<String>();
     
          for(Schema.SObjectField field : AllLeadFields.values()){
                if(field.getDescribe().isAccessible())
                    accessiblefields.add(field.getDescribe().getName());
            }
     
            String allfields='';
           
            for(String fieldname : accessiblefields)
                allfields += fieldname+',';
     
            allfields = allfields.subString(0,allfields.length()-1);
            
            
           //Query string to get all Accounts with the same email address
           
            String masterSOQLQuery = 'SELECT ' + allfields + ' FROM Account WHERE PersonEmail IN:  triggerEmail ORDER BY CreatedDate';
     
             
            // Query string to get all Accounts with the same email address excluding the Master Account
            String duplicatesSOQLQuery = 'SELECT ' + allfields + ' FROM Account WHERE PersonEmail IN: triggerEmail AND Id != :masterAccountID LIMIT 2';
     
            List<Account> matchingAccounts = database.query(masterSOQLQuery);
     
            Account masterAccount = matchingAccounts[0];
            Id masterAccountID = masterAccount.Id;
       
            List<Account> duplicateAccounts = database.query(duplicatesSOQLQuery);
           
            // Go through the master and duplicate record fields, and update the master record where its fields are blank, 
            //but the duplicate's is populated
            
            SObjectType AccountType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account');
            Map<String, Schema.sObjectField> mapFields = AccountType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
       
               for(String fieldName : mapFields.keySet())
                    {
                        if(masterAccount.get(fieldName) == null && duplicateAccounts[0].get(fieldName) != null)
                            {
                                masterAccount.put(fieldName, duplicateAccounts[0].get(fieldName));
                            }
                    } 
               
                    if(masterAccount != null) {
                        //merge masterAccount duplicateAccounts;  
                        Database.MergeResult[] results = Database.merge(masterAccount, duplicateAccounts, false);
                    }
               }
               Catch(Exception e){
                        system.debug('Exception ***'+e.getMessage());
                        System.debug('Exception_Line_No:' + e.getLineNumber());
                 } 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If an account has an active community user, it must be the master account in a merge.  You cannot delete an account with an active community user, so it cannot be the duplicate account (that is deleted by the merge).

Answer (score 0):

IsCustomerPortal is not an editable field, its set by the system when a Community/Portal user is created.
Rather than merging all the fields in your code, try NOT to update this field and it should go through fine.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. Is there a way we can skip the field "IsCustomerPortal " with my above code???